# Foundry's OAuth2 API Endpoints

Tags: palantir-foundry

I want to test the "Third-party applications" access using Postman.

When trying to obtain an OAuth token I am receiving a '404 Not Found' from Foundry. I suspect that I've configured the wrong URLs for the OAuth2 endpoints.

From reading the documentation

> https://<foundryhost.com>/workspace/documentation/product/foundry-backend/security-api#oauth2-api-endpoints

I put together the following 2 endpoints:

- Auth URL: `https://<foundryhost.com>/api/oauth2/authorize`
- Access Token URL: `https://<foundryhost.com>/api/oauth2/token`

Are those correct or am I missing something?

Comment: ok I did some further digging in the documentation. Between hostname and and /api I need the SERVICE_CONTEXT_PATH as  stated here: 
`https://<foundryhost.com>/workspace/documentation/product/foundry-backend/make-api-call#api-url-base`. But I cannot find the SERVICE_CONTEXT_PATH for  OAuth.

Comment: Not editing OPs question, so dropping links here: https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/platform-security-third-party/writing-oauth2-clients/#supporting-oauth2-integration and  https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/general/overview/making-requests/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track with the service context path - in this case it's `multipass` - which is Foundry's authentication service.

Try this:

```
authorize_url=FOUNDRY_STACK + 'multipass/api/oauth2/authorize',
access_token_url=FOUNDRY_STACK + 'multipass/api/oauth2/token'
```

Looks like the docs could do with some clarification. Will get that fixed.

Another gotcha to remember with OAuth2 on Foundry: the refresh token rotates on use - remember to save both when you request a new access token (this is compliant with the standard, but it is optional).